# want output as json instead of array while using criteria

Tags: arrays, json, spring, hibernate

This is my code and i am using projection to display only specific columns and i am getting the result as array.But i want the output as `json` what can i do to get the output as `json`.

Please help me out

```
public List<Educationlevel> getAllEducationlevel() {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Educationlevel.class);
            ProjectionList projlist =Projections.projectionList();
            projlist.add(Projections.property("education_level"));
            projlist.add(Projections.property("education_level_id"));
            projlist.add(Projections.property("country_id"));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("delete_flag", false));
            criteria.setProjection(projlist);
            return criteria.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

AND OUTPUT WHICH I AM GETTING

```
[["PG",0,2],["PHD",1,2]]
```

AND THE OUTPUT WHICH I AM EXPECTING
      IN THIS I WANT only 3 columns say education_level_id,country_id,education_level

```
{
    education_level_id: 0
    country_id: 2
    education_level: "PG"
    delete_flag: false
    insert_by: null
    insert_date: "2015-10-19 12:49:52.0"
    update_by: null
    update_date: "2015-10-19 12:49:52.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();    
jo.put("education_level", "PG");    
jo.put("education_level_id", "0");    
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();    
ja.put(jo);
```

Comment: what package i have to import thnaks for your reply

Comment: we have to import java-json jar to run this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2849567/rugmangathan                                   can you please suggest some better naswer...

Comment: you can dynamically pass your values in jo.put(education_level", $level) where $level will be your education_level

Comment: Thanks Dude... Got some idea

Comment: My pleasure. Was that helpful??